# Can I reference a number in Regex capture group, manipulate it, and then replace it back?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

For example I have a string like this:

```
Hello I am 'v0' to be added
```

I want to change it to:

```
Hello I am 'v1' to be added
```

So I am trying to substitute `'v0'` using below:

```
re.sub(r'(\W)v\d+(\W)', r'\1vnew\2', string)
```

And then now I get:

```
Hello I am 'vnew' to be added
```

But then I don't know how to manipulate numbers here.

Apparently `re.sub(r'(\W)v(\d+)(\W)', rf'\1v{int(\2)+1}\3', string)` does not work because `SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash`.

Any idea except doing these in separate steps, i.e. capture the number, add it and change it to a string before doing `re.sub()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increment the matched number by using a lambda function to replace the value. Note that you can simplify the code also by using lookarounds to avoid matching anything other than the digits after the `v`:

```
import re

s = 'Hello I am \'v0\' to be added'
s = re.sub(r'(?<=\Wv)\d+(?=\W)', lambda m: str(int(m.group(0)) + 1), s)
print(s)
```

Output

```
Hello I am 'v1' to be added
```